# {convertPrice price=$product.price} does not work in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

This is the error:

> Syntax error in template "file: / home / quetupec / public_html / clonpresta / modules / loyalty / views / templates / hook / shopping-cart .tpl "on line 32" {ls = 'that can be converted to a voucher of' mod = 'loyalty'} {convertPrice price = $ voucher} {if isset ($ guest_checkout) && $ guest_checkout}  *  {/ if}. 
>  "unknown tag 'convertPrice'

I have tried the other one like `Tools::displayPrice`, but I think it is deprecated in 1.7.6.

Has anyone worked around on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prestashop 1.7* you don't need to use any smarty or php functions. All necessary data are already transferred to templates within arrays with products information. So just use   $product.price and you will get already converted string. Also, be aware, that PS 1.6* and PS 1.7* templates and some modules aren't compatible in a storefront.

Comment: Man, I have been working with ps 1.6 for more than 2 years now becuase it was more stable than 1.7.. and 1.7 have bugs that were not being fixed.. I love prestashop, but the fixes just arent coming.. anyway, thanks.. I am starting to learn 1.7 and work on it moving forward once i get comfortable with it, because clients are asking more and more questions about migrating to 1.7.